# Select dialog does not load more data

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an select dialog. For performance reason, I have kept growing threshold as 100 records, out of 2000 total records.

So, the user can see 100 records when popovers open. I had written `growingScrollToLoad` so that when the user scrolls down, another 100 records get loaded.

However, this is not working somehow. Popover only shows 100 records initially, and even if I scroll down it doesn't load more data. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I had tried using all the tags/properties describe in [SAPUI5 Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/select-dialog/). Also, it works in https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectDialog/preview

```
<SelectDialog confirm="handleConfirm" 
              growingThreshold="100" 
              growingScrollToLoad="true" 
              items="{myModel>/AllData}"
              multiSelect="true" 
              noDataText="No data" 
              liveChange="handleSearchOnDialog" 
              title="Choose" 
              autoAdjustWidth="true">

    <StandardListItem id="idItemA" 
                      description="{Name}" 
                      iconDensityAware="false" 
                      iconInset="false" 
                      title="title" 
                      type="Active"/>
</SelectDialog>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution without changing control.

In XML file, I provided `growingThreshold="100" growing="true"` to Select dialog. In controller file, for `onOpen` event of Select dialog, I have written this piece of code:

```
var sGrowingThreshold = this._oSelectDialog.getGrowingThreshold(); //sGrowingThreshold will be 100

if (sGrowingThreshold) 
       {
                this._oSelectDialog.setGrowing(sGrowingThreshold);
       }
```

It worked and loads data everytime I scroll down till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the API:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SelectDialog

You will notice `growingScrollToLoad` is not listed in the property section of `sap.m.SelectDialog` ==> you cannot use this functionality

The property `growingScrollToLoad` is a property of `sap.m.ListBase`. So if you want to use it you need to create a custom dialog that has a `sap.m.List` or any other child of `sap.m.ListBase` as content.
(`sap.m.SelectDialog` is a direct child to `sap.ui.core.Control` -> no direct relation to `sap.m.ListBase`)

Comment: BUt as described in https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectDialog/preview, I can use growing threshold with Select dialog

Comment: you can, but the property 'growingScrollToLoad'  cannot be set by the developer! look at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectDialog/code/C.controller.js